# Python. Как работает генератор списка с lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Написал вот такую строчку:

```
a = [lambda x : x^n for n in range(10)]
```

При этом на каждой итерации

```
for i in range(10): print(a[i](2))
```

выдает 11, a

```
for i in range(10): print(a[2](i))
```

выдет:
9
8
11
10
13
12
15
14
1
0

Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то происходит следующее:

`a = [lambda x : x^n for n in range(10)]` - тут создается список функций.
Это то же самое, что и:

```
def xoring(x):
    for n in range(10):
        pass
    return x^n

a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(xoring)
```

Можно даже посмотреть что внутри списка и увидеть набор функций:

```
>>> a
[<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x029E1468>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02B7C300>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02B7C348>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02B7C390>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02B7C3D8>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02B7C420>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02B7C468>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02B7C4B0>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02B7C4F8>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02B7C540>]
```

Далее, `for i in range(10): print(a[i](2))`, 10 раз вызывается `i-я` функция из списка `a` и ей передается аргумент `2`. Так как функции одинаковые, то и результаты одинаковые.
Т.е. внутри происходит следующее:

`lambda x : x^n for n in range(10)` - здесь `i` изменяется от `0` до `9` и ксорится с `x`. Т.к. `x` = 2, то `x^i` даст такие результаты:

```
2^ 0  =  2
2^ 1  =  3
2^ 2  =  0
2^ 3  =  1
2^ 4  =  6
2^ 5  =  7
2^ 6  =  4
2^ 7  =  5
2^ 8  =  10
2^ 9  =  11
```

Последнее значения и возвращает функция.

Здесь `for i in range(10): print(a[2](i))` 10 раз вызывается функция с индексом `2` в списке `a` и ей передается значение `i`, которое меняется от `0` до `9`. То же самое, что и

```
for i in range(10):
    print(xoring(i))
```

Что в результате и дает

```
0 ^ 9 =  9
1 ^ 9 =  8
2 ^ 9 =  11
3 ^ 9 =  10
4 ^ 9 =  13
5 ^ 9 =  12
6 ^ 9 =  15
7 ^ 9 =  14
8 ^ 9 =  1
9 ^ 9 =  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам действительно необходимо XOR-ить (`x^n`) числа в десятичной системе? Предположу, что вы хотели провести операцию возведения в степень (`x**n`). При генерации вашего списка анонимных функций, все они зависят от переменной `n`, значение которой по завершении цикла `n = 9`.

> При этом на каждой итерации

```
for i in range(10): print(a[i](2))
```

> выдает 11

Тут понятно, ведь все функции в списке возвращают значение `x^9`.

Если вам все-таки нужно возведение в степень:

```
fun = lambda n: lambda x: x**n
a = [fun(n) for n in range(10)]
for i in range(10): print(a[i](2), end=' ')

Out: 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512
```